# What is the range of RC airplane transmitter?

Tags: transmitter, range

At buying a **controller and transmitter** for a wooden RC airplane, how to know the range it can fly within? I mean where to look in the specifications of the product?

Thank you in advance for help,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a 2.4 Ghz transmitter, the range is within the 'line of sight' between transmitter and receiver.
This means that the limiting factor of the range is that you should fly the airplane keeping the model aircraft within the 'visual range' as required also by the FAA/EASA/FCC/legal rules.
The actual theoretical range is reported in the transmitter/receiver manuals.

In practical terms the control range is usually about 1-2 Km and 600 mt-2 Km for the telemetry feature (range may vary based on local conditions, antenna type/installation and local WiFi interference) and depends upon the maximum transmission power allowed in your Country.
Please read the transmitter/receiver Data Sheet and manual before using them.

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to specify a range for a radio. The received signal strength depends on things like antenna orientation that changes as the model moves. Then the receiver's ability to pick out the signal depends on how much radio noise there is at the time. Then there's error handling in the receiver. If it loses one or two data packets out of every 100 (and is receiving thousands per second) you still have a solid link.

That said, model transmitters are designed to have more than enough range for large models at the limit of your eyesight. Most RC pilots don't have to worry about range.